# Bluetooth headphones not working, randomly disconnect

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

So I've spent quite a bit of time trying to get these headphones to work.

They're a pair of iKross foldable Bluetooth headphones, seen
[here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004U7N2K4). In order to get them to work with my computer, I also purchased [an adapter.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005Z5HT2M)

Since then, I've plugged in the adapter, installed the drivers, installed some more WIDCOMM drivers, installed the Bluetooth drivers that correspond to my ASUS ROG G75VW, installed every Windows Update driver that it asked, paired my headphones to the computer, connected my headphones to the computer, turned my headphones off and then on again and reconnected them, removed them from the computer, re-paired and re-connected them, had all my audio become disabled and unusable, including the speakers, uninstalled all my audio drivers, reinstalled the audio drivers that correspond to my ASUS ROG G75VW, reinstalled the Bluetooth drivers that correspond to my ASUS ROG G75VW, reinstalled my NVIDIA graphics and audio drivers, rebooted my computer numerous times throughout these steps, and finally have arrived at the point where the headphones are paired with and recognized by my computer, have a volume level bar in the Sounds panel, and I once actually managed to get **actual sound playing through them**, though I have yet to reproduce this (I believe it was done by disabling and re-enabling them, but that hasn't worked again yet).

So here is my current list of unresolved problems:

- When connected as an audio device, no sound plays through the headphones, though it recognizes them and the built-in microphone works fine (if I tell the computer to listen to it, I can hear my voice crisply through them).
- The headphones will, after about 30 seconds connected, automatically disconnect.

If I could solve these problems, my headphones would finally work, and I would be so, so happy. They may be related. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: I managed to get the sound streaming through the headphones again when I connected them, but it still disconnects. It also sounds really awful and tinny, like it's being played loudly through speakers at a crowded party.

EDIT2: Finally managed to get it working. After I turned the adapter on and off again, connecting properly streamed audio to the headphones. However, it sounded tinny and awful, nothing like on my phone. So, I then **uninstalled the Atheros Bluetooth Suite.** This killed the crab-- I mean, fixed the problem. It no longer disconnects and the audio sounds fine. Good luck to anyone else who encounters these problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be an overlapping use of same frequencies by different equipment

One possibility could be wifi, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#2.4.C2.A0GHz_.28802.11b.2Fg.2Fn.29 and compare then with

http://www.newlogic.com/products/Bluetooth-Tutorial-2001.pdf
the bluetooth adapter operate at a frequency spectrum in the 2.402 GHz to 2.480 GHz range.

You should use CommView for WiFi (Windows) or wifi analyzer (Android) to make sure that your network isn't causing that random disconnections, proceed disabling your wifi (physically turn it off) and re connect, if this solves the problem, try changing your wifi channel configurations other good tries could be turning off others BT devices.

By the way, the BT should be able to alternate channels and avoid interferences, but I have issues with a router in an train station that causes this kinda of disconnections, until I managed a way to wait the train in a point of the platform that is distant of that router.

Comment: It may be worth noting that I don't have this problem until I installed the ROG Bluetooth drivers. That changes the default Windows control screen for the device, and causes the disconnecting problem. Maybe it's related? But without the drivers I haven't had any luck making it recognize them as an audio device at all.